# WordPress: Show box after X paragraphs of content

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a box with additional informations after a fixed number of paragraphs in `the_content`.

I know, that I could use the more tag for such a purpose. That's what I'm doing now. And there is also an option to use shortcodes in the post. 
But that's all not what I want/need because these things change the post itself.

With the following code I could count every `<p>`-tag in the post.

```
$query = get_post(get_the_ID());
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);
$p_count = substr_count($content, '<p>');
```

Is there a way to select a specific `<p>` tag (e.g. the thrid) and add my code after it?

An other idea is to count the tags with the following code:

```
$query = get_post(get_the_ID());
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $query->post_content);

$p_counts = substr_count($content, '<p>');
$p = 0;

foreach ($p_counts as $p_count) {
        $p++;
}
echo $p;
```

Maybe there is a way to add the info box after a specific `<p>` number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74242/96806

This is the code:

```
<?php

$paragraphAfter[1] = '<div>AFTER FIRST</div>'; //display after the first paragraph
$paragraphAfter[3] = '<div>AFTER THIRD</div>'; //display after the third paragraph
$paragraphAfter[5] = '<div>AFTER FIFtH</div>'; //display after the fifth paragraph

$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$content = explode("</p>", $content);
$count = count($content);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( array_key_exists($i, $paragraphAfter) ) {
        echo $paragraphAfter[$i];
    }
    echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't images or other tags in your content, you can easily do it with jQuery

Comment: it's very unlikely to not have images in the post  ;-)